# Copying SPListItemVersion Created By to SPListItem

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to assign the following:

```
spListItem["Author"] = itemVersion["Created By"];
```

If the itemVersion["Created By"] is "12;#crazy", then I would expect spListItem["Author"] to be same "12;#crazy". But, the value is only "12". I don't understand why the ";#crazy" seems to be ignored. Help!

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear in your question but I assume itemVersion is SPListItemVersion. That class has CreatedBy property so there's no need to use itemVersion["Created By"].

It's not a problem that Author column contains only user ID after the assignment. It will be extended by the name of user after the call of Update() method on spListItem.

Answer (score 0):

When you save spListItem try to use the method UpdateOverwriteVersion. This method could help to modify system fields like Created, Modified and Modified By